# Error "DDL statements are not allowed in transactions" while create new product In Magento 2.3.4

Tags: database, magento2.3.4, mysql-indexes

When i try to create new product it showing below error

"DDL statements are not allowed in transactions"

I have done research and found that in "vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php"

```
protected $_ddlRoutines = ['alt', 'cre', 'ren', 'dro', 'tru'];

if (in_array($startSql, $this->_ddlRoutines) && strcasecmp($sqlMessage[1], 'temporary') !== 0) {
                throw new ConnectionException(AdapterInterface::ERROR_DDL_MESSAGE, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

It give error for this query "ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)".

Simply it checks if sql starts with ALT and and its not temporary it throws error.

Any Idea why it happens.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while edit product and I have fixed it by updating indexer "Update On Save" to "Update On Schedule".